# C# Order Dictionary Keys with multiple values

Tags: c#, .net

I've created a dictionary in C# with multiple values per key:

Edit: The structure has been corrected after suggestion from comments:

```
var exampleDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>>() 
{ 
    { 
        "Apple", 
            new Dictionary<string, double> 
            { 
                { "Weight", 82 }, 
                {"Size", 10}, 
                { "Number", 32 } 
            } 
    }, 
    { 
        "Orange", 
            new Dictionary<string, double> 
            { 
                { "Weight", 73 }, 
                {"Size", 9}, 
                { "Number", 63 } 
            } 
    }, 
};
```

Is there a way I can sort the dictionary keys by a specific value. E.g. If I wanted to sort by the "Number" value in descending order so the dictionary would have **Orange** first and then **Apple.**

Comment: This would be much easier if you created a `new List<Produce>()` where `Produce` is a class with fields `Name`, `Weight`, et al.

Comment: I recommend you to use List<Class> instead of use Dictionary<Dictionary>

Comment: To be clear, you can't **sort** (in place) a dictionary in the way that you want - you can however `OrderBy` the data _into a different data structure_ in the order that you want.

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful since the sample inputs are causing some confusion.

Comment: @mjwills I guess the OP meant: `var exampleDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>>() {
{ "Apple", new Dictionary<string, double> { { "Weight", 82 }, {"Size", 10}, { "Number", 32 } } },
{ "Orange", new Dictionary<string, double> { { "Weight", 73 }, {"Size", 9}, { "Number", 63 } } },
};`

Comment: @KlausGütter The need for guessing is the problem. ;) The OP has provided data in a format which is clearly inferior to an _unambiguous_ format (i.e. code). ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most easily done using LINQ:

```
exampleDictionary.OrderByDescending(e => e.Value["Number"])
```

If it is not guaranteed that a "Number" entry exists, better use TryGetValue instead of `[..]` to avoid KeyNotFoundException:

```
exampleDictionary.OrderByDescending(e => e.Value.TryGetValue("Number", out var n) ? n : 0)
```

(This will sort entries without Number as if the number were 0).

As pointed out by some comments: OrderByDescending does not sort the dictionary in-place (this is impossible), but return an ordered enumerable, so it can be used e.g. as:

```
foreach (var entry in exampleDictionary.OrderByDescending(e => e.Value["Number"]))
{
   Console.WriteLine(entry.Key);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @KlausGütter, that worked perfectly. I've set my dictionary as `new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>>` and wrote that example json output assuming it would look like that, so it might be that I didn't display that json correctly.

Comment: It would be better to clarify that neither of examples actually *sort dictionary*. Code as written looks like it sorts in-place which is clearly not the case.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Indeed, added to my answer. Thanks